# subtracting columns from other columns in R data.frame

Tags: r

I have a rather odd problematic going on. 
Let X be a dataset with about 300.000 rows and 300 columns. Assume that a lot of the entrys in X have missing values (which in this case equal zero in reality).
What i want to do:
subtract for each row the third column from the farmost right column, which is not missing.
save the difference, as well as the colname. if the difference is not negative, search for the next not missing value in the row, going left, and now calculate the difference between the already calculated difference and the new not missing value. do this as long the difference is not negative and each time save the colname.

i already wrote something, to do this for me - the problem is, it effectively takes about 53h to finish and i reckon that the dataset isn't even big in particular.
could you guys please help me :(

```
b <- c()
length(b) <- 193145
d <- 0;
for (i in (1:193145))
{
  d <- 0;
  for (j in (271:4))
  {
      while(is.na(x[i,j]))
      {
        j <- j-1;
      }
      d <- (d+x[i,j]);
      if ((x[i,3]-d)&&(j>3))
      {
        b[i] <- colnames(x)[j]
        j <- 2
      }
      else if (j==3)
      {
        b[i] <- "older"
      }
      j<-j-1;

  }
  i<-i+1;
}
```

UPDATE:
Hey guys, thanks for the fast responses. The i<-i+1 bit is completely false, as I forgot,that by the end of an for loop,i gets incremented anyways. 
okay, a short example

```
 A B C D E F G H I 
 AB001BWIF085 SS13 2980 NA NA 4000 NA NA 3000  
 AB001BWCE475 SS12 3800 NA NA 5000 NA NA 2000
 AB001BWIF087 SS13 2980 NA NA 2000 NA NA  500
```

what do i want to do? i want to loop over every row, and subtract the value in the third column from every value in the following columns, beginning from the farmost right.i want the COLNAME of the object,which is not NA, to be saved with the difference to my value from the third column.
and do you have some examples for the vectorize package? as i couldn't really grasp the ones presented inside of the help.
Thanks again! :)

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
 A col_name_1 difference_1 col_name_2 difference_2 ...
 AB001BWIF085 I -20 NA NA
 AB001BWCE475 I 1200 F -3800 
 AB001BWIF087 I 2480 F 480 "older"
```

If the difference is not going to drop below 0, i want an entry to be "older", indicating this case.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what your code is doing.  When you start with `for (i in 1:193145)`, we expect the code to run with `i=1`, then `i=2`, and so on.  But you have `i<-i+1` at the end of the loop, which means that actually `i` gets incremented twice in the loop, so we only get the odd numbers.  What happens inside the `for j` loop is even more confusing.  As a general principle, you shouldn't modify the loop variable.

Comment: @AlexanderHansyz His for and while loop are interfering.  Try this and note what it does:  `for (j in 10:4){ while(j>6){ j <- j-1 ; }; print(j); }
` Here it prints `6 6 6 6 6 5 4 `.  So the `10:4` is an array stored in memory, and changing the `j` with a `while` loop still goes back to the next temporary array value.  Plus that will slow it down.

Comment: It's also difficult to follow your natural language version... too many assumptions that we can read your mind or see what you are pointing at. You should post a simplified dataset with 5 or six columns and say 10 rows that illustrate the issues and also post what you see at the "correct" answer.

Comment: There are two things that typically make R run slow.  One is `for` loops.  You have two nested loops, making (maybe?) around 50 million iterations.  Search for the word `vectorise` or `vectorise` for some hints on how to get rid of the loop.  The other is R's "copy on modify" behaviour.  Each time you do `b[i]=something`, the entire `b` vector gets copied again.  The fact that you start with `b=NULL` means that the size of `b` is constantly changing through the loop, which slows things down further.  You need to preallocate storage for `b`: again, a bit of searching will give you many hints.

Comment: updated original post.

Comment: Please also post the intended result for your example data. "vectorize" is not a package (although there is a function `Vectorize`), but a concept of the R language. It basically means functions can accept vectors and return vectors, which often makes it unnecessary to use loops.

Comment: I updated original posting again. Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: @AlexanderHanysz `for` loops are not inherently slow in R. They just often result in people naively writing code that involve lots of copying/growing. So it's all really just your second reason.

Comment: I'm think of things like: `x=1:1e6 ; system.time(y<-x+1) ; system.time(for (i in 1:1e6) y[i]=x[i]+1)`.  The second time is a lot longer.  If "`for` loops are slow" is the wrong way to explain this, then how else do you describe it?